# How do I render into a sub-region of a texture atlas with XNA / HLSL?

Tags: xna, hlsl, texture-atlas, viewport

Is it possible to render into a texture atlas?

I've been wondering how to reduce the number of textures required for shadow-mapping, and came across a blog post [here](http://john-chapman-graphics.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/shadow-map-allocation.html) about rendering up to sixteen shadow maps into one texture-atlas.

According to the blog post mentioned above, these are the steps required:

1. The first step is writing to the texture; bind it to the framebuffer and set the viewport to render into the texture sub-region.

2. When accessing the sub-region, scale/bias the texture coordinates as follows: scale = region size / texture size, bias = region offset / texture size.

I understand this, but I'm not sure how to alter the viewport specifically to allow me to render into a certain square of the texture. I've found plenty of information about reading from it (up-sampling and down-sampling) but I don't know how I'd manipulate the viewport specifically to render into a small square region of the screen, and how I'd do this with a texture smaller than the back-buffer.

I'm using XNA and HLSL at the moment because it's simpler than SharpDX, and there's no point in messing around with that until I've got the theory working 100%.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Set the [`GraphicsDevice.Viewport`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.viewport_members.aspx) property to a new `Viewport` struct with the values you want.  Set `X` and `Y` offset, set `Width` and `Height`.  All these values are in units of pixels, so the size of the target texture doesn't matter.

[Here is a simple code example.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb313965%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx)  It uses separate cameras to accomplish different perspectives per viewport, but you don't need that portion.  You only need the lines that assign different `Viewport`s.

Comment: Thanks. I was confused and thought it was something else entirely. Whoops. :S